# Get the user input number and compare that with a simple database on flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

currently learning flutter and trying to do a simple game.

I have  list with prices and product name.

My idea is to display a random image, and someone tries to guess the price.

Currently I'm stuck on the comparing the input price with the price on the list.

This is what I currently have

```
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCustomForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyCustomFormState createState() => _MyCustomFormState();
}

class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  final myController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    @override
    void dispose() {
      myController.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int randomIndex = Random().nextInt(products.length);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          "Guess the Price!",
          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Pacifico"),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: InkWell(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Spacer(),
              Container(
                  child: Text(
                '${products[randomIndex].productName}',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                ),
              )),
              Container(
                  child: TextFormField(
                      controller: myController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]')),
                      ],
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "The price is ${products[randomIndex].productPrice}", //debuging 
                      ))),
              Spacer(),
              Container(
                child: Text((() {
                  if ({products[randomIndex].productPrice} == {myController.text}) {
                    return "The price is correct!";
                  }
                  return "The price is wrong!";
                })()),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What should I add to do the work? Should I add a listener, so when the text changes, he auto updates the value of the myController.text , or should I go through other ways?

Sorry if this is a newbie error, but currently searching for solutions!

Comment: Can you show how you wrote the `products` variable used.

Comment: Hello! So I made something like this!
`class productTest {
int price;
String name;

productTest(this.price, this.name);

}

List<productTest> products = [
productTest(20, 'Remote')
];`

Comment: I have posted a working solution with my notes. If my answer is helpful, please mark it as correct with the green checkmark next to it. Thank you and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to move randomIndex outside of the build method otherwise it would always change when the state changes and you can't compare it to user input.

I am not sure exactly what you want but I think this will give you a hint how to do it.

```
 class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
   const MyCustomForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
  _MyCustomFormState createState() => _MyCustomFormState();
}

class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
 final myController = TextEditingController();
 String guessText = "";
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
 int randomIndex = Random().nextInt(products.length);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text(
      "Guess the Price!",
      style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Pacifico"),
     ),
   ),
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: InkWell(
    child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Spacer(),
          Container(
              child: Text(
            '${products[randomIndex].productName}',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30,
            ),
          )),
          Container(
              child: TextFormField(
                  controller: myController,
               onChanged: (value) {
                 if (products[randomIndex].productPrice == value) {
                   guessText =  "The price is correct!";
                     setState(() {
                     });
                    }
                  },
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]')),
                  ],
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "The price is ${products[randomIndex].productPrice}", //debuging 
                  ))),
          Spacer(),
          Container(
            child: Text(guessText),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working solution. There were quite a few changes, so have a look.

You need to have a button that gives a user the chance to move to the next product (or random). Also, you call `product[..].productPrice`--this is unnecessary because you should call `product[..].price`.

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Product {
  final String name;
  final int price;

  Product(this.name, this.price);
}

class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCustomForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyCustomFormState createState() => _MyCustomFormState();
}

class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  final myController = TextEditingController();

  List<Product> products = [
    Product('p1', 5),
    Product('p2', 10),
  ];

  int productIndex = 0;

  int enteredPrice = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    @override
    void dispose() {
      myController.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int randomIndex = Random().nextInt(products.length);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          "Guess the Price!",
          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Pacifico"),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: InkWell(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              const Spacer(),
              Text(
                products[productIndex].name,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: myController,
                onChanged: (_) {
                  enteredPrice = int.parse(myController.text);
                  setState(() {});
                },
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                    RegExp(r'[0-9]'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              Text(
                (() {
                  return checkEnteredPrice(0);
                })(),
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    productIndex++;
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  child: const Text('Next Product'))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  String checkEnteredPrice(int productIndex) {
    if (products[productIndex].price == enteredPrice) {
      return "The price is correct!";
    } else {
      return "The price is wrong!";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an example here, check the comment for descrition. Check images for demo result.

For your code, i have some advice:

- do not `(){}()`, use `? :` or something else instead, it look too long and make me confuse.
- recomend to separate your logic and your render, more specific is put `Random` in `build` that cause `randomIndex` changes everytime widget rendered. put them in some function that caller able.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

const products = <Map<String, dynamic>>[
  {'name': 'HotDog', 'price': 5},
  {'name': 'Televison', 'price': 699},
  {'name': 'Carrot', 'price': 10},
];

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: const App(),
    );
  }
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  int? randomIndex; // stored random index product
  String? answer; // stored your answer

  bool get submitAnswered =>
      answer != null; // getter check user was answerd yet?
  int? get correctPrice => randomIndex != null
      ? products[randomIndex!]['price']
      : null; // getter to get correct answer

  // function to generate randomIndex, reset your answer
  void getRandomIndex() {
    int? newIndex;
    do {
      newIndex = Random().nextInt(products.length);
    } while (newIndex == randomIndex);

    setState(() {
      randomIndex = newIndex;
      answer = null;
      controller.text = '';
    });
  }

  // function to submit your answer
  void onSubmitted(String value) {
    setState(() {
      answer = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          "Guess the Price!",
          style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Pacifico"),
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              // Button that generate new randomIndex
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: getRandomIndex,
                child: const Text('Get random product'),
              ),
              // Only render when have randomIndex
              if (randomIndex != null) ...[
                // Display name of prouct
                Center(
                  child: Text(products[randomIndex!]['name']),
                ),
                // Only render when not answered yet, show text input and submit button
                if (!submitAnswered) ...[
                  TextField(
                    controller: controller,
                    onSubmitted: onSubmitted,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'your price',
                    ),
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () => onSubmitted(controller.text),
                    child: const Text('Submit your price'),
                  ),
                ] else
                  // Only render when answered, showing your result, correct or not
                  Center(
                    child: Text(int.tryParse(answer!) == correctPrice
                        ? 'Correct price ($correctPrice)'
                        : 'Wrong price, your price is $answer and correct price is $correctPrice'),
                  ),
              ],
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]